# Seg Fault from Array of Nodes

Tags: arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a project and I'm trying build an array of nodes as a heap so that in each index of the array, I can store a name and value. Essentially I want my constructor to set the value of the first index to -1 so that I can tell whether or not it is empty later on (value of -1 indicates an empty index).

The problem is that I'm getting a seg fault and I do not know why. Here is the erroneous code:

Header File:

```
class tripe
{

 public:

  tripe();
  void initialize(string filename); //initialize tripe data struct
  void insert(string name, int grade); //insert given pair into structure
  void search(string prefix); //print list of entries that matches prefix
  void findMin(); //print min grade entry
  void buildheap(string name,string grade,int size);

  heapnode *heap[100]; //TROUBLESOME VARIABLE
  trinode *head;
  trinode *let[25];

};

class heapnode
{

 public:

  string student;
  int score; //WANT THIS TO BE -1 FOR FIRST INDEX OF HEAP ARRAY
};
```

C++ File:

```
tripe::tripe()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      heap[i] = NULL;
    }

  heap[1]->score = -1; //SEG FAULT
}
```

In fact I've noticed that whenever to try to access the score variable in my heap array, I get a segault without fail. Does my constructor need to do something else? Any help with this problem would be much appreciated!

P.S. I am required to use an array of nodes for this project, so the implementation for my heap cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a NULL in heap[1]. When you indirect through a NULL, you get a segmentation fault. That's what's supposed to happen. heap is not an array of nodes, but an array of pointers to nodes. If that's intentional, then you must allocate some memory for those pointers to point to before you actually use those pointers. Since you say you are required to use an "array of nodes", I'll guess that that is true and that you therefore need to change your declaration to be an array of type heapnode:

```
heapnode heap[100];
```

Then your constructor would possibly look like this:

```
tripe::tripe()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      heap[i].score = -1;
    }
}
```

Obviously, any other references to nodes in the heap would have to change to use the "." operator instead of "->".

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I'm still a bit of a noob working with nodes and pointers so I could not figure this out for the life of me. I've changed the declaration and the ->'s to .'s and it all works. Thanks again!